# My React fetch calls are overburdening the server. How to solve this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ajax, mongodb, fetch

I have a big platform application, with a lot of API routes and constant fetching of GETS, PUTS, DELETES and POSTS.

My application works over a Mongo Database and an Node Server. I don't have access to server side, but I'm pretty sure the problem's on my side.

See, when I start fetching with a rebooted server and DB everything goes smoothly, but after some time and, let's say, a hundred calls, everything starts to get very slow. The server seems to be overburden by my fetch calls and I don't know how to kill these calls when changing to a new React Component.

Actually, at some point, everything just dies and the server returns this:

```
{
   error: "pool has been destroyed"
}
```

So I have to reboot my server and my database.

This is how the GET call looks on my service.js file:

```
async get(URI) {
    const token = getToken();
    try {
        let response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/${URI}`, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencode', 'token': token }});
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

So, everytime I create a new component that needs to do a GET call, I do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    AuthService.get('/some-uri')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            console.log(result)
        }
    )
},[])
```

PS: last night, I checked the server log with the server-side developer and he told me that I was doing like 2 thousand calls already.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't show enough of what you're doing on the client side for us to really offer ideas on how to do client-side things more efficiently.  The biggest goal is to minimize the number of calls to the server so you try to combine as many things into one call to the server as possible.  And, then you want to use calls to the server that are more efficient.  For example, if you need data for items in the database A, B and C, it's usually more efficient to request the data for all three in one API call rather than three separate calls.

Comment: On the server-side, if the server is getting slower and slower as you use it, then that sounds like a server-side problem (triggered by your client use, but actually a server-side problem).  It sounds to me like the server may be leaking some resource (perhaps a DB connection) or something like that and eventually it fails because of a lack of resources.  FYI, a server should be just fine handling 2000 API calls (spread out over a little bit of time) without the server shutting down.

Comment: I don't know react very well, but perhaps you don't want to be doing an API call for every single component.  Maybe you should get the data you need for the page in a small number of calls and then cache it locally and use it as you create your components.  I know it's architrecturally convenient to make components completely self sufficient. bit sometimes practical issues force us to deviate a bit from the ideal architecture.

Comment: I do have a service for multiple calls on one Component. I'll add it to the example. The thing is when I change from component to another, the last call stays open on the server.

Comment: What call stays open on the server?  What does that mean?

Comment: @jfriend00 All of them. All of the calls. Let find an example with the server side guy.

Comment: If you make a call with `fetch()` and something stays open on the server and isn't later reused or recycled (and thus is a leak), that's just a bug in the server - nothing to do with your client code.

Comment: You need to debug and profile your code. We don't know what your application does or why it's slowing down. For pool destroyed error, you most likely have client lifecycle wrong (client is closed with outstanding incomplete operations).

Comment: @D.SM That sounds as the possible cause. How can I fix this?

Comment: Debug your program.

Comment: @D.SM Sorry, what makes you think that I didn't do that already? Wouldn't be here otherwise.

Comment: *We* cannot debug your program for you. We don't know what it does and what is wrong with it.